# Код где касания реализованы с помощью GestureDetector.OnGestureListener

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, ontouchlistener

вот прикладываю полный код программки

```
    public class MainActivity1 extends Activity  { 

   public static float touchX = 50,touchY= 50; 
    private float korX = touchX, korY = touchY, initX=0, initY=0, XX = 0, YY = 0; 
    static int width; 
    static int heigth; 


    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
         GraphicsView myview = new GraphicsView(this);  
        setContentView(myview);  
        display(); 

    } 

    public void display(){ 
         width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
         heigth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); 
        return; 
    } 
    public class GraphicsView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 


        private DrawThread drawThread; 

        public GraphicsView(Context context) { 
            super(context); 
            getHolder().addCallback(this); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
            drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), getResources()); 
            drawThread.setRunning(true); 
            drawThread.start(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
            boolean retry = true; 
            drawThread.setRunning(false); 
            while (retry) { 
                try { 
                    drawThread.join(); 
                    retry = false; 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { 

                } 
            } 
        } 


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 

            switch (event.getAction()) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

                    korX = touchX; 
                    korY = touchY; 

                    if((event.getRawY()> heigth*0.827) && (event.getRawX() > width * 0.2291) && event.getRawX() < width *0.7701 ) { 

                        initX = event.getRawX(); 
                        initY = event.getRawY(); 

                    } 

                    return true; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 



                    if((event.getRawY()> heigth*0.827) && (event.getRawX() > width * 0.2291) && event.getRawX() < width *0.7701 ){ 

                         touchX = (korX + (event.getRawX()- initX)); 
                         touchY = (korY + (event.getRawY() - initY)); 

                     } 

                    // getHolder().addCallback(this); 
                    return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 
}
```

и второй поток , хотя он уже не относится к вопросу

```
public class DrawThread extends Thread { 

    private boolean running = false; 
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; 
    private Matrix matrix; 
    private long prevTime; 

public Bitmap bitmap; 

public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,Resources resources){ 
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; 
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.face_box); 
} 

public  void  setRunning(boolean running){ 
    this.running = running;                  
} 

@Override 
public  void  run(){ 

    while (running){ 
        Canvas canvas = null; 



        try { 
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null); 
            if (canvas == null) 
                continue; 
          synchronized (surfaceHolder) { 

              canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); 
                onDraw(canvas); 

          } 

        } finally { 
            if (canvas != null){ 
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 


        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, MainActivity1.touchX, MainActivity1.touchY, null); 
    } 
  }
```

Проще всего конечно, если бы вы запустили это у себя и в эмуляторе увидели все косяки алгоритма сами. 
Я повторюсь, опираясь на переменные тут использованные. в условии в ACTION_MOVE: и вообще в алгоритме не учтен тот случай , когда палец непрерывно выходит из из области ограниченной координатами и вновь так же неотрывно входит туда. Получается что initX (точка прикосновения к экрану от которой считается разница между этой точкой и текущей координатой) не изменяется . А требуется чтобы при входе в область ограниченной координатами первая координата стала этим initX , а следующие уже будут относительно неё считать расстояние на которое требуется сместить саму иконку . 
 В общем либо я не соображу как алгоритм правильный написать, либо надо добавлять какие нибудь методы или использовать интерфейс гестуредетектор..

Comment: Это методы не жизненного цикла, а событий - срабатывают при обнаружении тапа, скролла, длинного тапа, смахивания (в них нет последовательности действий, а только ответ на реакции пользователя)

Comment: ну вот расскажи мне пожалуйста что значат все эти параметры onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) и в других событиях интерфейса Gesture что значит каждый из параметров. Могу ли я какое нибудь из этих событий использовать вместе Action_Move ,чтобы оно возвращало мне две координаты , прошлую и текущую при неотрывном ведении пальцем по экрану.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                korX = touchX;
                korY = touchY;
                initX = event.getRawX();
                initY = event.getRawY();




                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:



                if((event.getRawY()> heigth*0.827) && (event.getRawX() > width * 0.2291) && event.getRawX() < width *0.7701 ){
                    if (flag) {
                        korX = touchX;
                        korY = touchY;
                        initX = event.getRawX();
                        initY = event.getRawY();
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        touchX = (korX + (event.getRawX() - initX));
                        touchY = (korY + (event.getRawY() - initY));
                    }

                 }
                else {
                    flag = true;

                }


                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

изначально flag  = true
Спасибо тем кто объяснял и отвечал на мои неправильные вопросы)

Answer (score 2):

Используй: `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` нажатие и `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`  отпускание

Comment: не понимаю , что мне это даст. я нажимаю палец , потом веду им по экрану, но не отпускаю, я не поднимаю палец и на обработку этого события мне нет смысла что либо ставить. мне нужен такой обработчик , который в событии при котором я неотрывно двигаю палец возвращался мне прошлую и текущую координату. MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE возвращает только   текущую, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN так же текущую координату .

Comment: Хорошо, давай попробуем так: 'public MotionEvent MyOldEvent;' и внутри эвентов присваивай/анализируй эту переменную

Comment: Ммм MyoldEvent ..такого еще ни где не видел..как будет доступ к компу, начну анализировать

Comment: И еще вопрос, а можно ли если я веду палец по экрану , не отрывая, поставить условие при которых , если палец вышел из диапазона определенных координат, событие action_move и вообще весь метод onTouch прекращал работу и возобнавлял работу снова,  когда палец возвращается в диапазон этих координат, возобновлял работу так что первая координата в этой области обрабатывается как action_down и далее как action_move? Пробовал всякие break прописывать, но не выходит

Comment: Контролируй выход за границы диапазона либо внутри `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:` Либо размести `View` элемент, с нужными границами диапазона, и установи `OnTouchListener` именно для него

Comment: Внутри case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE я и контроллирую условием if . Если условие выполняется, то из текущей координаты вычитывается координата первого касания.  В этом и проблема,  что если палец покинул диапазон координат прописанный в условии case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE продолжает работать и при входе пальца снова а эту область сработает не down   а move.   Приложу Код когда буду дома,  будет понятней. Если на   view повесить ontouchlistner , то событие move так же будет  обрабатывать координаты за областью  view. В общем лучше приложу код

Comment: УРааа, оказалось всё таки не нужно никакие гестуредетекторы и другие методы использовать. просто случайно на свежую голову пришла идея правильно алгоритма.